# How to get a common Encoding between C#.NET, PHP and MySQL?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I have a C#-Application which sends data to a php and the php stores the data into a mysql-database. And if I have an `äöü` or some other stuff (I´m urlencoding it, so there are also `&%$/")=!` contained in the string) it will be stored in the database as `È└/` or something like that. So it´s definely an encoding-problem. How can I solve it?

**EDIT:**
I´m using these pieces of code:
C#:

```
WebClient.DownloadString(apiString + "sendMessage.php?user=" + user + "&message=" + message);
```

PHP:

```
$verbindung = mysql_connect("nightking.org", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("apidb");
$ergebnis = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `apidb`.`tm_chatdata` (`username` ,`time` ,`message`) VALUES ('" . $_GET['message'] . "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , '" . $_GET['user'] . "');");
```

When I call the values again:

PHP:

```
$verbindung = mysql_connect("nightking.org", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("apidb");
$ergebnis = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM `tm_chatdata` ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 38)ORDER BY time ASC;");
$firstOne = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
    if($firstOne)
        $firstOne = false;
    else
    {
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    if($row->username == "system")
    {
        echo "[" . $row->message . "]";
    }
    else
    {
        if($row->username == "command")
        {
            echo "*".$row->message;
        }
        else
        {
            echo /* $row->time . " " . */$row->username . ": " . $row->message;
        }
    }
}
```

C#:

```
WebClient.DownloadString(apiString + "getMessages.php");
```

The MySQL collation type is now changed to utf8_bin and it still does not work.

Comment: Where are you doing URL-encoding and why? You only (generally) need to URL-encode text if they're going into a URL.

Comment: I´m sending the data via get to a php-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to audit the path of which data in your application goes through.

Starting in C# land, you'll probably be using `HttpWebRequest` to send data to your PHP script. If you're only setting querystring or HTTP header values then you don't need to encode anything: HttpWebRequest will do that for you. If you're setting POSTdata using `request.GetRequestStream` then it depends on what kind of form submission you're doing, [though HTML5 states by default this should be UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) with non-ASCII characters converted to numeric values. Note that this only concerns over-the-wire format, the PHP environment will automatically handle this for you.

PHP does not have built-in support for Unicode: all strings can be considered as arrays of single-bytes, thus provided they are not manipulated then they will preserve data on a per-byte basis. For manipulation, use the `mbstring` extension.

MySQL presents another issue as it allows per-table encoding. The default is `latin1` though I'd recommend setting this to `utf8` or `utf16` for the sake of consistency. Even worse: you have to [contend with connection encoding too](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php).

So there really aren't any simple answers, but I would suggest making sure that everything is consistent:

- Ensure that your method of encoding (both the form-encoding and the actual 'numerical encoding' of characters) is declared in your HTTP client in your C# application.
- Ensure you aren't manipulating multibyte strings in an unsafe manner in PHP and that you're handling them in a way consistent with the encoding declared in the HTTP headers of the incoming request by the C# program.
- Ensure that your MySQL tables are all using the same encoding and it's an appropriate encoding (e.g. utf8 or utf16) and that if the incoming-data has a different encoding then you'll convert it accordingly before saving it to the database.

Comment: I´m using WebClient.DownoadString()

Comment: +1 Because your answer isright, but I still don´t know how to solve it.